# Create a custom search in Entity Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm a newby in Symfony, but I'm trying to develop a small system to my job.

I only have experience in ZF1 and I'm not used to use Doctrine. But I need to create a custom Query for my page, and searching in the internet I discover that when I generate a new Entity, I can create a new one that has the same **name + Repository** in the class name.

For example, I have a Entity named *Schedule* and a Repository named *ScheduleRepository*.

And in the ScheduleRepository that I'm tryong to generate my custom Query.

```
class ScheduleRepository extends EntityRepository
{
   public function findAll()
   {
      $rsm = new ResultSetMapping();

      # ScheduleType
      $rsm->addEntityResult( "ApplicationBundle\Entity\Schedule", "s" );
      $rsm->addFieldResult( "s", "schedule_id", "id" );
      $rsm->addFieldResult( "s", "usersId", "usersId" );
      $rsm->addFieldResult( "s", "updatedAt", "updatedAt" );
      $rsm->addFieldResult( "s", "start", "createdAt" );
      $rsm->addFieldResult( "s", "finish", "createdAt" );
      $rsm->addFieldResult( "s", "schedulesTypeId", "schedulesTypeId" );      

      # User
      $rsm->addJoinedEntityResult( "ApplicationBundle\Entity\User", "u", "s", "users" );
      $rsm->addFieldResult( "u", "users_id", "id" );
      $rsm->addFieldResult( "u", "name", "name" );

      $rsm->addJoinedEntityResult( "ApplicationBundle\Entity\ScheduleType", "st", "s", "scheduleType" );
      $rsm->addFieldResult( "st", "schedule_type_id", "id" );
      $rsm->addFieldResult( "st", "schedule_type_name", "name" );

      # custom SQL
      $sql = "SELECT
               s.id AS schedule_id,
               s.updated_at,
               st.id AS schedule_type_id,
               st.name AS schedule_type_name,
               u.id AS users_id,
               u.name,
               MAX( CASE WHEN s.schedules_type_id = 2 THEN s.created_at END ) AS start,
               MAX( CASE WHEN s.schedules_type_id = 2 THEN s.created_at END ) AS finish
             FROM
               schedules s
             INNER JOIN users u ON u.id = s.users_id
             INNER JOIN schedules_type st ON st.id = s.schedules_type_id
             GROUP BY 
               s.users_id,
               DATE_FORMAT( s.created_at, '%Y-%m-%d' ) 
             ORDER BY 
               DATE_FORMAT( s.created_at, '%Y-%m-%d' ) ASC";

      return $this->_em->createNativeQuery( $sql, $rsm )->getResult();
   }
```

And when I dump the return I receive this:

```
Schedule {#2187
  -id: 1
  -users: User {#2189
    -id: 1
    -name: "Felipe"
    -email: null
    -password: null
    -active: null
    -createdAt: null
    -updatedAt: null
    #schedule: PersistentCollection {#2190
      -snapshot: []
      -owner: User {#2189}
      -association: array:15 [ …15]
      -em: EntityManager {#2092 …10}
      -backRefFieldName: "users"
      -typeClass: ClassMetadata {#2101 …}
      -isDirty: false
      -initialized: false
      -coll: ArrayCollection {#2191
        -_elements: []
      }
    }
  }
  -scheduleType: ScheduleType {#2180
    -id: 1
    -name: "Entrada"
    #schedule: PersistentCollection {#2181
      -snapshot: []
      -owner: ScheduleType {#2180}
      -association: array:15 [ …15]
      -em: EntityManager {#2092 …10}
      -backRefFieldName: "scheduleType"
      -typeClass: ClassMetadata {#2101 …}
      -isDirty: false
      -initialized: false
      -coll: ArrayCollection {#2182
        -_elements: []
      }
    }
  }
  -createdAt: DateTime {#2188
    +"date": "2015-02-18 19:31:39"
    +"timezone_type": 3
    +"timezone": "UTC"
  }
  -updatedAt: null
}
```

**My questions are**:

- Why I didn't receive the *start* and *finish* alias that I create in my Query?
- Why my *updatedAt* is null if I have value in that field?

Thank you.

**Update**

I'm trying what the user [user3749178]:(https://stackoverflow.com/users/3749178/user3749178) said, using this library github.com/mapado/MysqlDoctrineFunctions I generate again the Query, but in DQL, and now I receive an error:

`[Syntax Error] line 0, col 73: Error: Unexpected ')'`

in this DQL:

`SELECT u, s, st, MAX(CASE WHEN s.schedulesTypeId = 2 THEN s.createdAt END) AS start FROM ApplicationBundle:Schedule s JOIN s.users u JOIN s.scheduleType st`

Comment: What is reason you don't use DQL?

Comment: I tryed, but I always get an error. I look in the internet, and I don't think that Doctrine have some functions from MySQL integrated. eg. DATE_TIME, MAX...

Comment: I am sure MAX is there. You probably just use it in wrong way. As for DATE_TIME you should define new DQL function if you need. There are tons of ready to use open source code, like that one with installation instruction: https://github.com/mapado/MysqlDoctrineFunctions

Comment: I'll try it, thank you. Using this DQL function, I can create the ALIAS in the DQL?

Comment: If you mean aliases for column, then yes, you can. But in your code you want only entities, so things like that doesn't matter, because doctrine map them for you.

Comment: I also recommend you to not override `findAll()` method in repository. Just use new method name. It's better to not mess with default repository functions, because third party code and symfony components sometimes use them.

Comment: Ok, I'll rename the function. Thank you.

Comment: Other question, I got this DQL: SELECT u, s, st FROM ApplicationBundle:Schedule s JOIN s.users u JOIN s.scheduleType st ---- but when I add this: MAX(CASE WHEN s.schedulesTypeId = 2 THEN s.createdAt END) AS start ---- I receive a error: [Syntax Error] line 0, col 73: Error: Unexpected ')'

Comment: There is no CASE in DQL. You can use JOIN...WITH instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
  $rsm->addFieldResult( "s", "updatedAt", "updatedAt" );
  $rsm->addFieldResult( "s", "start", "createdAt" );
  $rsm->addFieldResult( "s", "finish", "createdAt" );
```

updatedAt should be updated_at.  Notice also that you have start/finish both mapped to the same field.  I suspect the finish will override the start.  And since you are restricting yourself the mysql then I'd suggest just using camelCase for your aliases to reduce confusion.

It would probably be better to use DQL but I think you are almost there.

DQL only supports the following sql functions: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#dql-functions

You can however add your own.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/common_extensions.html

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/custom_dql_functions.html